# Scroll on Dropdown of antD component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, antd

I am looking for scroll if data longer than 10,

```
<Dropdown overlay={menu}>
    <a className="ant-dropdown-link" onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
      Hover me <DownOutlined />
    </a>
  </Dropdown>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-star-m7rhf?file=/index.js

This where I am trying to achieve the scroll but not sure how to make it work..
can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can do this with CSS like;

```
.ant-dropdown-menu {
    max-height: 250px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

but this one doesn't check item count. If you want to check item count, you can do this with styled-components module.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the below properties to the class "ant-dropdown":

```
overflow-y: scroll;
max-height: 250px;
```

adjust max height based on your requirement.